# Show panel, only when a collection is loaded

Tags: python

How to show a panel, only when a particular collection exist (or appended)?

Here a bit more explanation of what I am aiming for in case the question is not clear:

[image]

In the screenshot above you see there is a panel called 3point light Ctrl. What I want is that the panel "3Point Light Ctrl" only shows up after the user clicked on "Add 3 Point Light" in the "Add to scene" panel.

Often I see a poll function in other addons like:

```
@classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
```

And so I thought I could do it as follows:

```
@classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return return bpy.data.collections[“ThreePointLight”]
```

But that doesn't work, and I realize it is expecting context, not bpy.data.  Any idea how I can do this?  (It's for Blender 2.80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use python's membership operator: `in`

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    return "ThreePointLight" in bpy.data.collections
```

Using `bpy.data.collections[*name string*]` would result in an `KeyError` in the event the name does not exist.

Comment: Would be a  `KeyError` if the name doesn't exist. Could also use `collection.get(key) is not None`

Comment: @proxeIO That was the trick. That makes it quite easy to make a dynamic menu.  Thanks!  See answer: return "ThreePointLight" in bpy.data.collections

Comment: @batFINGER Corrected